# How do I get input from the user in Java (console)?

Tags: java, io, user-input

Below I have a copy of my entire code for a tic tac toe program. I know its not much yet, but I'm stuck at the getting input part. I've managed to get 1 input from the user and then print it out (column), but then when I try to enter something different for row, it gives me whatever I was using for column. Any thoughts on how to fix it?

I'm just learning java, please be gentle.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println ("Please make your first move by entering a column and then a row, like this: c r \n");

        int columnGotten = 0;
        int rowGotten = 0;

        //gets your column number choice

        BufferedReader columnInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        try {
            columnGotten = Integer.parseInt(columnInput.readLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println ("If you're not going to play fair, I'm going to leave. Bye.");
            return;         
        }

        System.out.print ("Your column is " + columnGotten + "\n");

        //gets your row number choice

        BufferedReader rowInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));

        try {
            rowGotten = Integer.parseInt(rowInput.readLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            System.out.println ("If you're not going to play fair, I'm going to leave. Bye.");
            return;         
        }

        System.out.print ("Your row is " + columnGotten);           

    }

}
```

Comment: You shall not create a new Reader, just use the previous reader.

Comment: I tried to do that, but it still gave me the same error (displaying the old input).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

`System.out.print ("Your row is " + columnGotten);`

to

`System.out.print ("Your row is " + rowGotten);`

Comment: Don't worry. Even the most advanced devs do such mistakes. Just keep in mind whenever you copy/paste to double-check the changes. ;)

Comment: I still need to wait 5 mins, there's some kind of timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Try input using Scanner.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner();
int x = sc.nextInt();
String s = sc.nextLine();
```

And so on. Hope it helps.

Comment: I'll try this - it seems to be less complicated than using BufferedReader - do they have the same functionality?

Comment: Yes. It is more neat and less error prone. `javap java.util.Scanner` for more info.

Comment: Thank you both, I'll be checking this out later tonight.